# removing an element with a userscript

Tags: userscripts

First attempt at a userscript, and despite finding numerous examples on the internet of how to remove elements from a page, none of them work (and this looks like one of the most basic applications of a userscript, too).

Using violentmonkey-2.12.8 on this page:

https://www.zerohedge.com/economics/2020-greatest-hits-most-popular-articles-past-year-and-look-ahead

I want to remove the "exitModalOverlay" div (disabling it in the developer tools does exactly what I want), which blacks out the page (preventing me from reading it).

I will insert one of the more common techniques I have found (which doesn't work). I would appreciate any method which does. Thanks.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @namespace   confused
// @name        zehohedge_remove_subscription_popup
// @version     1
// @description removes the overlay div that asks to subscribe
// @match       https://www.zerohedge.com/*
// @grant       none
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

var todelete = document.getElementById('exitModalOverlay');
if (todelete) { todelete.parentNode.removeChild(todelete); }
```

Comment: When I tested above URL, there weren't any element with the id `exitModalOverlay`.

Comment: @erosman  
  
I didn't notice that the element didn't come from the original URL, but I tracked it down, and it appears to come from:

https://www.zerohedge.com/_next/static/css/002da6e1033acc0b4b1b.css
  
The URL I gave above references the css file twice. Using view source, the css reference appears in the following two lines:  

`href="/_next/static/css/002da6e1033acc0b4b1b.css" as="style"/><link rel="stylesheet"
href="/_next/static/css/002da6e1033acc0b4b1b.css" data-n-p=""/><link rel="preload"`

Comment: If you give a web page that has the element, it would be easier to check. In order to remove an element, the actual page is needed for testing.

Comment: The page has the element when loaded. When I load the page in a browser, and inspect it, I get the following html:

https://pastebin.com/wRdXtzaq

Comment: Please provide a link to the page that has the element with that id. When I go to `https://www.zerohedge.com/economics/2020-greatest-hits-most-popular-articles-past-year-and-look-ahead` there isnt any element with that id and `document.getElementById('exitModalOverlay')` is `null`. However, in general, the code you have above is fine. In order to test it, you must provide a link that has the element with that id.

Comment: Do you have javascript enabled when loading that page? While the individual articles load fine without javascript, the main page won't work without it (it shows empty squares as placeholders for articles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe so...

```
window.onload = function() {
var todelete = document.querySelector('#exitModalOverlay');
todelete.outerHTML = '';
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
var todelete = document.querySelector('#exitModalOverlay');
todelete.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectily, and I could apply it immediately without any extensions or modifications to the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the post & comments, it seems the element is loaded/created after the DOM. In that case, you would need to run the script after page loading is complete.

Although when testing on the link provided with JavaScript enabled (`https://www.zerohedge.com/economics/2020-greatest-hits-most-popular-articles-past-year-and-look-ahead`), the element does not appear, here is an example of how you can remove the item.
It is possible there are other factors involved (e.g. browser, country, login, cookies etc).

ViolentMonkey by *default* runs on `document-end` which is after DOM loaded but before all external elements are loaded.
Setting the userscript to run at `document-idle` will run after everything is loaded.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @namespace   confused
// @name        zehohedge_remove_subscription_popup
// @version     1
// @description removes the overlay div that asks to subscribe
// @match       https://www.zerohedge.com/*
// @grant       none
// @noframes
// @run-at      document-idle 
// ==/UserScript==

// find element
const todelete = document.getElementById('exitModalOverlay');
// remove element if found
if (todelete) { todelete.remove(); }
```

Removing the element is not the only way to get rid of an element. You can also use CSS to achieve a similar outcome by setting its `display` to `none`. For example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @namespace   confused
// @name        zehohedge_remove_subscription_popup
// @version     1
// @description removes the overlay div that asks to subscribe
// @match       https://www.zerohedge.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

const css = `
#exitModalOverlay {
  display: none;
}`;
GM_addStyle(css);
```

Using JavaScript to apply CSS to the element without `GM_addStyle` (although not as good as above)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @namespace   confused
// @name        zehohedge_remove_subscription_popup
// @version     1
// @description removes the overlay div that asks to subscribe
// @match       https://www.zerohedge.com/*
// @grant       none
// @noframes
// @run-at      document-idle 
// ==/UserScript==

// find element
const todelete = document.getElementById('exitModalOverlay');
// remove element if found
if (todelete) { todelete.style.display = 'none'; }
```

It is worth noting that CSS applies all the time (unless over-written specifically), even if an element is created later, while JavaScript applies at the time it runs and will not apply to elements created later (without additional methods to cause it to run again).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Your explanations will most likely end up more helpful in the long run than a simple solution for this particular site.